# Overlaying the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity which displays a fullscreen `bitmap` image. When the user clicks on the image, the action bar will be hidden. Currently, the `bitmap` will resize once the action bar is hidden. To address this issue, I have tried overlaying the action bar, as described in the [developer guides](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html).

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NormalActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/my_green</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This displays my solid green action bar, but the `windowActionBarOverlay` call doesn't seem to do anything- the `bitmap` will still resize when I hide the action bar.

My minimum sdk is currently set to 16/Jelly Bean/4.1.x, and I am running Lollipop.

What did I do wrong? I appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the overlaying option directly to your app's style theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NormalActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```